# Visual Studio opens Development Servers for all websites in my project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I currently have a Visual Studio solution with 8 web applications.
When I try run one of these applications, 8 instances of the Casini Web Development Servers are launched.

Is there anyway to specify that only the web application I have set as startup project will be launched and not all 8.

I am using Visual Studio 2008

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Select the Solution.  Right click and select Properties.  Under Common Properties select Startup Projects.  The select Single Startup Project, select the project you want to startup, and press Apply/OK.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is a project option `Always start when debugging`. Select Project in Solution View and in Properties Window set this option to `false`. Without it the server is started even if project is not chosen as startup project.